# How to create .ipa file using Xcode?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, production, ips

Please tell me the complete procedure to build my app & use it on a real iPhone.

Answer (score 283, accepted):

### **In Xcode Version 10.0**

---

1. Go to **Window -> Organizer**
2. Then select your app archive from archives
3. Then click the **"Distribute App"** button on right panel

[image]

4. Then follow the below steps

**Step 1**

[image]

**Step 2**

[image]

**Step 3**

[image]

**Step 4**

[image]

**Step 5**

[image]

**Step 6** : Finally select the place you want to save the .ipa file

[image]

### **In Xcode Version 9.2**

---

1. Go to **Window** **-> Organizer**
2. Then select your app archive from archives
3. Then click the "**Upload to App Store**" button on right panel
4. Then follow the following steps

**Step 1**
[image]

**Step 2**
[image]

**Step 3**
[image]

**Step 4**
Finally select the place you want to save the .ipa file

[image]

Comment: I'm using Xcode 10.1 and in the path: **Window -> Organizer** there's no app archive. How to create my app's archive firstly in Xcode 10.1, please?

Comment: hope this [link](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/devf37a1db04) will help you

Comment: Thanks, this helped, but I get these two errors when performing "Archive" on Xcode 10.1: *clang: error: -ffunction-sections is not supported with -fembed-bitcode*, *clang: error: -fdata-sections is not supported with -fembed-bitcode*. Would you help, please?

Comment: I found some similar problem in  this [SO tread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301649/xcode-4-clang-error) this is regarding about earlier Xcode version but similar situation like you. hope this will help you

Comment: Also you could try out switching to legacy build system. As i remember you could found it in following location. **File > Project/Workspace Settings**

Comment: I searched much for the sections remarked on that thread but found nothing close to my Xcode, unfortunately. [Here](https://imgur.com/driWRrJ) is the *Clang* sections of my Xcode. I also tested both *New/Legacy Build System*, but both had the same result! :(

Comment: sorry @Franky I think it would be better. if you could post separate question regarding this matter on SO. Someone will help you who has faced similar problem like this

Comment: Thanks @coder. Did [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55198638/clang-errors-when-trying-to-archive-an-ios-app-in-xcode-10-1).

Comment: No problem @franky. Great I saw that you have found the solution.

Comment: Yeah, the one who answered is great, and I thank you too for suggesting to create a separate question on that. :)

Comment: I exported my app with the "iOS App Store" option (Xcode 10.2.1), then copied the .ipa file to my iPad as shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6w7xORCVJC4#t=1m25s). It installed the app but the icon was grey and the app also only wiggled once instead of starting (see question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56988327/2016165)). Changing the "Build Configuration" from "Debug" to "Release" didn't help either. The second .ipa I exported with "Ad Hoc" instead works just fine now - no matter what "Build Configuration" I'm using.

Comment: How do I install ipa file on my iOS device?

Answer (score 101):

***In addition to kus answer.***

***There are some changes in Xcode 8.0***

***Step 1:***
*Change scheme destination to `Generic IOS device`.*

***Step 2:***
*Click `Product` > `Archive` > once this is complete open up the Organiser and click the latest version.*

***Step 3:***
*Click on `Export...` option from right side of organiser window.*

***Step 4:***
*Select a method for export > Choose correct signing > Save to Destination.*

---

> ***Xcode 10.0***

***Step 3:***
*From Right Side Panel Click on Distribute App.*

***Step 4:***
*Select Method of distribution and click next.*

***Step 5:***
  *It Opens up distribution option window. Select* ***All compatible device variants*** and *click next*.

***Step 6:*** *Choose signing certificate.*

***Step 7:*** *It will open up Preparing archive for distribution window. it takes few min.*

***Step 8:*** *It will open up Archives window. Click on export and save it.*

---

Comment: It seems like this requires a $99 membership in Apple Developer Program

Answer (score 52):

Click `Product` > `Archive` from the menu, once this is complete open up the `Organiser` and click the latest version > `Distribute` > `Save for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployment` > Choose correct signing > Save to destination

Comment: While exporting there are 4 options. iOS app store, ad-hoc, enterprise and development. Which option should i choose? My requirement is this ipa is required by the qa team for testing purpose.

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper You can choose ad-hoc or development option in your case.

Answer (score 35):

**In Xcode-11.2.1**

You might be see different pattern for uploading IPA
*Steps*:-

i) Add your Apple Developer id in **Xcode** -> **preferences** -> **accounts**

*ii) Clean Build Folder :-*

[image]

*iii) Archive*

[image]

*iv) Tap on Distribute App*

[image]

*v) Choose Ad-hoc to distribute on designated device*

[image]

*vi) Tricky part -> User can download app from company's website URL. Many of us might get stuck and start creating website url to upload **ipa**, which is not required. Simply write google website url with **https**  **:)***

[image]

[image]

*vii) Click on export and you get ipa.*

[image]

*viii) Visit https://www.diawi.com/ & drag and drop ipa you have downloaded. & share the link to your client/user who want to test :)*

Comment: Nice to mention that if you are pointing to an emulator then Archive will be disabled

Comment: @RaulH is there any other way to select archive without actually connecting the real iphone device ?  Like by pointing to simulator only ?

Comment: @Aayush Shah you have to select 'Any iOS Device', it s before the simulators in the simulator list.

Answer (score 33):

You will need to `Build` and `Archive` your project. You may need to check what code signing settings you have in the project and executable.

Use the Organiser to select your archive version and then you can `Share` that version of your project. You will need to select the correct code signing again. It will allow you to save the `.ipa` file where you want.

Drag and drop the `.ipa` file into iTunes and then sync with your iPhone.

**EDIT:** Here are some more detailed instructions including screenshots;

[How to distribute ad hoc build with XCode 4](http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/how-to-distribute-ad-hoc-build-with-xcode-4/)

Answer (score 26):

**Archive process (using Xcode 8.3.2)**

*Note : If you are using creating IPA using drag-and-drop process using iTunes Mac app then this is no longer applicable for iTunes 12.7 since **there is no built-in App store in iTunes 12.7.***

1. Select `‘Generic iOS Device`’ on device list in Xcode

[image: Step 1]

2. Clean the project (`cmd + shift + k` as shortcut)

[image: Step 2]

3. Go to `Product` -> `Archive` your project

[image: Step 3]

4. Once archive is succeeded this will open a window with archived project
5. You can validate your archive by pressing `Validate` (optional step but recommended)
6. Now press on `Export` button

[image: Step 4 5 6]

7. This will open list of method for export. Select the export method as per your requirement and click on `Next` button.

[image: Step 7]

8. This will show `list of team for provisioning`. Select accordingly and press on ‘`Choose`’ button.

[image: Step 8]

9. Now you’ve to select Device support -> `Export one app for all compatible devices` (recommended). If you want IPA for specific device then select the device variant from list and press on ‘`Next`’ button.

[image: Step 9]

10. Now you’ll be able to see the ‘`Summary`’ and then press on ‘`Next`’ button

[image: Step 10]

11. Thereafter IPA file generation beings and later you’ll be able to `export the IPA as [App Name - Date Time]` and then press on ‘`Done`’.

[image: Step 11]

Comment: When i do step 7 i receive this error: **Distribution requires enrollment in the Apple Developer Program. Visit https://developer.apple.com/account to enroll.** what should i do?

Answer (score 9):

**In Xcode Version 14.2 (14C18)**

Follow the below steps for generating an IPA file
Steps:-

**Step-1:**

Verify your **Apple Developer Account** in **Xcode -> settings -> accounts**.

[image]
[image]

**Step-2:**

Select the target **simulator device** as **Any iOS Device(arm64)** and then in **Xcode** navigate go to **Product -> clean Build Folder**.

After project gets cleaned successfully again in **Xcode** navigate to **Product -> Archive**.

[image]

**Step-3:**

After successfully completed building archive file you will able to see a window like below then click on **Distribute App** and select **Development** and then click on **next** and again **next** with default
development distribution options available

[image]
[image]

**Step-4:**

After this select **Automatically manage signing** and then **next** then you will find the **appname.ipa** file created like below

[image]
[image]

**Step-5:**

Then click on **export** and save it to the folder as you wish here I'm saving it to **Documents** folder below
[image]
[image]

**Step-6:**

Visit https://www.diawi.com/ & drag and drop ipa you have created. & share the link to your users ‍

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way, follow the steps :

step 1: After Archive project, right click on project and select show in finder

step 2: Right click on that project and select show as Show package contents, in that go to `Products>Applications`

step 3: Right click on projectname.app

step 4: Copy projectname.app into a empty folder and zip the folder(foldername.zip)

step 5: Change the zipfolder extension to .ipa(foldername.zip -> foldername.ipa)

step 6: Now you have the final .ipa file

Answer (score 1):

At the time of Building select device as iOS device. Then build the application. Select Product->Archive  then select Share and save the .ipa file. Rename the ipa file to .zip and double click on zip file and you will get .app file in the folder. then compress the .app file of the application and iTunesArtwork image. it will be in the format .zip rename .zip to .ipa file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the steps I followed to export the .ipa

- Validate the archive
- Click on on distribute the app
- Click the distribution method
- Choose the export in the next screen (The screen shown only if the archive is validated)