# Real ads (admob) not showing up in Live app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, admob

I have a lite version of one of my app live in apple store. I have integrated admob in that.
I was successfully able to see ads while testing, both test ads & real ads sometimes. Now as the app is live, I can notice only test ad is showing up.
"this is a test ad"

Link to app, [cheque Track](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/chequetrack-lite/id739893884?mt=8)

[image: Here is the screen sample]

Answer (score 2):

Please check the following points before publish your app.

1. You should use iPhone app id of AdMob to display ads on iPhone and iPad app id of AdMob to display ads on iPad. Because there is no universal type app in AdMob.
2. In case of BannerView use size provided by the AdMob SDK. Please don't use your custom defined size and use origin with appropriate value.
3. Click on the your project -> goto build settings -> add value to "Other Linker flag" to "-ObjC".
4. To know errors or loading successful or not define delegate methods provided for specific add and don't forget to assign "self" to ad's delegate property.
5. Always use latest SDK.
6. Test mode off in app setting of AdMob app.

After performing these steps and modifying code, it is time to test your app by creating ipa of the app in real device. In iOS 7 if you run iPhone app in iPad [UIDevice currentDevice].model returns "iPad" . So check iPad ipa in iPad and iPhone ipa in iPhone.

two use links to create ipa and install it in your device.

[create ipa link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5499249/2666902)

[install ipa on your device](http://jaym2503.blogspot.in/2012/09/how-to-install-ipa-file-to-iphone-ipod.html)

Please inform if any issue comes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

read this somewhere.. thought it might help

log in to your AdMob account, go into "Sites And Apps", hover your mouse pointer over the App in question and click on "Manage Setting". Then, click on the "App Setting" tab and you will see a "Test Mode" option. In that, select the "Disable test mode for all requests" option and hit "Save Settings" at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)bannerView;
-(void)adView:(GADBannerView *)bannerView didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error;
```

There can be number of reasons for not showing the Live ads.

1. Check your google admob account for the payment info. If not filled, fill it.
2. Check if your device is registered as test device, else you may get suspension from the google for 30 days or so.
3. Use correct platform and ad unit ID from the admob account for live ads and wait for a while, it takes time to show ads.
4. You can check the delegate methods and print the logs:

In my case, I was getting error as *{ 'error': 'Request Error: No ad to show.', 'adType':'banner' }*.
But it showed at the client side, after I delivered to the client. So, I think that this issue was due to the reason that google had no advertisements in my region.