# Admob Ads not coming in ios app after Publish

Tags: ios, admob

Recently I have published a iOS app which tested in real device and simulator only by "command + R" pressing not by .ipa file. I have published the app few weeks ago. When I am testing on the released version , I found admob banner ads not coming. I have followed the help guide provided at developer site of admob . 
If anybody have solution please reply.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I also have a similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489345/real-ads-admob-not-showing-up-in-live-app) with my app [Cheque Track Lite](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/chequetrack-lite/id739893884?mt=8)

Comment: @BalramTiwari I have posted an answer to your link, you may check and please inform me if it works or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the following points before publish your app.

1. You should use iPhone app id of AdMob to display ads on iPhone and iPad app id of AdMob to display ads on iPad. Because there is no universal type app in AdMob.
2. In case of BannerView use size provided by the AdMob SDK. Please don't use your custom defined size and use origin with appropriate value.
3. Click on the your project -> goto build settings -> add value to "Other Linker flag" to "-ObjC".
4. To know errors or loading successful or not define delegate methods provided for specific add and don't forget to assign "self" to ad's delegate property.
5. Always use latest SDK.
6. Test mode off in app setting of AdMob app.

After performing these steps and modifying code test your app by creating ipa of the app in real device. In iOS 7 if you run iPhone app in iPad [UIDevice currentDevice].model returns "iPad" . So check iPad ipa in iPad and iPhone ipa in iPhone.

two use links to create ipa and install it in your device.

[create ipa link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5499249/2666902)

[install ipa on your device](http://jaym2503.blogspot.in/2012/09/how-to-install-ipa-file-to-iphone-ipod.html)

Please inform if any issue comes. Thanks