# How to get .apk and .ipa file from flutter?

Tags: flutter, apk, ipa, flutter-ios

I am new to flutter programming and I've created a demo app, its running fine on both android and iOS devices. I want to see .apk and .ipa file in flutter. Can anyone help me to get these files from Flutter? Where can I see these files in folders or is there any other solution.

Comment: https://flutter.io/android-release/#building-a-release-apk. Maybe the debug apk is in a similar folder/path

Answer (score 94, accepted):

For Android an APK is generated every time you build the app, e.g. with `flutter run`. You will find that in your project folder under `<project>/build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk`. If you want a release APK, have a look at [the docs](https://flutter.io/android-release/).

I'm not an iOS person, so I'm not sure an IPA is generated during development as in android. But looking at [these docs](https://flutter.io/ios-release/) it seems you can follow the standard steps on xcode to get it, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499125/how-to-create-ipa-file-using-xcode).

Comment: Using this method, if you share the apk and install that apk to another device, then it says app is not installed. Below answer works perfectly.

Comment: This method won't work for Android debug apps. App won't get installed message will be shown

Comment: you can't install this apk on physical device , you have to create apk using command "( flutter build apk --release ) .

Comment: If you are not an iOS person then may be you should not have answered the question. Also, the answers are wrong for android and generic for iOS!

Answer (score 233):

For apk (Android) you need to run the command :

```
flutter build apk --release
```

If you want to split the apks per abi (Split Apk) then run

```
flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi
```

For ipa (iOS) you need to run the command :

```
flutter build ios --release
```

From the console

P.S. `--release` is optional as it is by default
if you need debug build, just replace `--release` with `--debug`

you can find the released APK or IPA files form

```
build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk
```

Comment: Hi, where can we locate debug build of ios (is it .ipa?), I want ios file on the lines of .apk to share it to client and testers. Tried and tired of no answers online, thank you!

Comment: Do we need a physical ios device to generate .ipa or is simulator enough?

Comment: You can find it in the build/outputs folder of your project, Further, it won’t give you an ipa file, instead it will give you a compiled application file

Comment: ok, so one thing I'm confused about. On Android, after flutter build apk, I can do flutter install. What about after build iOS --debug or --release ... what do I do to install on the device?

Comment: seems the same. I'll try it out.

Comment: $flutter build ios --release gives this error "Building for iOS is only supported on the Mac."

Comment: Yes, because it needs Xcode to be installed which is only possible in a mackintosh

Comment: But its giving me a apk of too big size like in my case i am getting apk of size 70mb

Comment: Flutter usually creates large apk sizes, but 70MB is too large for that too. Make sure you aren't using any dependency that is messing up with your apk size, try to analyse your apk and check which component is taking most of the space.

Answer (score 31):

For apk (Android) run the command :

```
flutter build apk --release
```

For ipa (iOS) run the command :

```
flutter build ios --release
```

Then to get actual .ipa file, open xcode -> Product -> archive -> Distribute App -> Ad Hoc -> Export

You can then save the .ipa(which is inside the Runner folder) file in any location

Answer (score 6):

To get an apk, it is simple. Just use :

```
flutter build apk
```

To get an ipa, It is more complicated. First use :

```
flutter build ipa
```

Be careful to use **`flutter build ipa`**, not `flutter build ios`, because the second one builds a "`.app`" file instead of "`.xcarchives`" file.

Once you have the "`.xcarchives`" file, you can open it in XCode and click on "Distribute the app" to export an ipa file on your computer.

Answer (score 5):

If you want this apk and .ipa with flavour then you can refer below commands for internal and production.

**iOS**:

`flutter build ios --debug --flavor internal`

`flutter build ios --release --flavor production`

**android**:

`flutter build apk --debug --flavor internal`

`flutter build apk --release --flavor production`

Comment: And where is the .ipa file?

Comment: you can find on below path

 1) /build/ios/ipa

 2) /build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app

Answer (score 4):

I also had this question and had a really tough time finding the right solution.
First of all in the terminal of your code editor type:

```
flutter build apk --release
```

and after that go to this location:

```
yourAppFolder/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk
```

I do not do development for iOS so I don't know much about that.

Comment: I am trying to use above command ..but every time it shows command not found..I don't know what's going wrong at my end..Do I need to set any path for this on mac?

Comment: make sure you are in the folder of the project.

Answer (score 3):

For Android, an APK is generated every time you build the app, e.g. with flutter run. You will find that in your project folder under `<project>/build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.`

Comment: Don't you mean `<project>/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk`?

Answer (score 2):

Follow below steps to get .apk and .ipa from flutter app in Mac system

1. First, Enter below command in your terminal to go your project directory

   **cd $(PROJECT FOLDER PATH)**
2. For android apk build to upload store, Enter below command

   **sudo $(FLUTTER SDK PATH till bin)/flutter build apk --release**
3. To get ios ipa , Enter below command

   **sudo $(FLUTTER SDK PATH till bin)/flutter build ios --release**

Comment: Hi @Preethi G, could you please elaborate on your question? You can also follow the tutorial about how to answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @tashiro92 this is an answer, not a question

Answer (score 0):

For iOS:

Step 1: open terminal and type `cd "your flutter sdk path"`

Step 2: `cd export PATH=/Users/yourname/Downloads/flutter/bin:$PATH`

Step 3: `cd "your project path"`

Step 4: `flutter build ios --release`

run step 1 to 4 in terminal.

After that open android studio and go to iOS folder path and open `project.pbxproj` file with ios module and in xcode you need to choose generic ios device and select archive, it will generate ipa build for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Android**(After adding release build type run below command which will generate release apk with below version)

```
flutter build apk --build-name=1.0.1 --build-number=1
```

**iOS**

```
flutter build ios --release
```

For a detail explanation read the below article.

https://medium.com/@ralphbergmann/versioning-with-flutter-299869e68af4

Answer (score 0):

For apk, you can use flutter build apk --release to get the release version of your apk on either windows/macOS.

For ipa, you have to use flutter build ios --release to get the release version of your apk on macOS.

Note: You can get a ipa on macOS only.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything on the answers and nothing works with me!!

so i deleted flutter sdk folder and download it again The Flutter Sdk and restarted my ide and worked with me

Answer (score -1):

> Updated for iOS :-

first you need to go to your current working directory and run the following command;

```
flutter build ios --release
```

After successfully completion of build, you can find build on below path;

```
/Users/sanjaybalaji/Documents/KiranFlutterApps/hb_calculator/build/ios/iphoneos/Runn
er.app.
```

*you can check below screenshots for more details.*

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You can find your app apk after you run the app at path
<project_dir>/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk

Comment: Your answer doesn't add anything new to the problem. Same solution is provided by many already.