# I made an android app using flutter, is there a way to build an IPA from the same code?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, ipa

So I built an android app using flutter on Android studio but I see that in order to build an IPA I need to use Xcode on a MAC device so I was really wondering what to do to transfer the flutter app to Xcode? or do I need to rewrite the whole code again?
I tried using a ci/cd service too it would build the app in .app format but would never install on my IOS device, I followed another procedure to transfer .app to .ipa but still it can't be installed so I'd be really grateful if someone could give me an insight on what to do at least

thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get .apk and .ipa file from flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50645703/how-to-get-apk-and-ipa-file-from-flutter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flutter can directly compile an iOS and Android version. You do not need to rewrite anything(unless you have Android native code in your App). Just open your Project on a Mac with Flutter and Xcode installed and compile it by running `flutter build ios`.

You won't be able to do anything without a Mac though. Since Xcode is required to sign your App and Apple doesn't let you do that on any other OS.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification is it possible to use a virtual machine with mac os to do this? or does it have to be a mac device?

Comment: @Geo I have not tried it myself. But a virtual machine should work. Atleast I don't see a reason why it wouldn't.

Comment: @Geo No problem at all. Good luck!