how to solve "your project requires a newer version"
BUILD FAILED in 1m 21s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                             82.6s

┌─ Flutter Fix ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                            │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then update │
│ D:\FLUTTER_PROJECTS\testlumi\android\build.gradle:                                                │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'                                                           │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1

I just to need to build the apk into appbundle to deploy the application but even though I update the kotlin version the error shows repeatedly. Anyone know how to clear out the error?

This question is similar to: flutter : Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Can you share minimal code of build.gradle (android->build.gradle)

buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '2.0.0'
repositories {
google()
mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
    classpath "com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:secrets-gradle-plugin:2.0.1"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}

}
allprojects {
repositories {
google()
mavenCentral()
}
}

Have you tried with Kotlin version 1.8.10 and 1.9.10

You would need to switch from Project to Android folder. If you are using android studio, the update would happen automatically, if it does not (assuming you have switched from project to android), click on android project name -> android -> build.gradle, it will begin updating every components needed.

i tired but still the error remaining

Try running Flutter clean in the Project folder, then get dependencies. Also run your app on a physical device before trying to get the apk.
You should look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50645703/how-to-get-apk-and-ipa-file-from-flutter

Add ext.kotlin_version and kotlin dependency in <app>/android/build.gradle file.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.0' //use latest
    ...
}

dependencies { 
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    ...
}

