# Clang errors when trying to archive an iOS app in Xcode 10.1

Tags: ios, xcode, clang, xcode10.1

I've installed an iOS app on my iPhone using Xcode 10.1 and when  hitting `Product -> Archive`, the following two errors come up:

[image]

Several times cleaned the project in Xcode and neither *New* nor *Legacy Build System* has an impact on the result.

How to solve these errors, please?

Comment: Don’t embed bitcode?

Comment: I don't know of that, sorry. I created my iOS app using QML then made use of its *.xcodeproj* file to modify the settings on Xcode, like the name, ID etc of the developer, png images for icon and launch image, and then installed the app on my iDevice. Now if I want to have the *.ipa* file of that app, the first step is archiving as illustrated above. But unfortunately I get those errors.

Comment: I disabled *bitcode* and it seemingly was worked out! I should thank you. But is it OK to disable *bitcode*? Or when should I enable or disable this please? I'm a very new programmer of iOS and it's the first days I'm using Xcode.

Comment: Personally I think bitcode is the work of the devil and I always disable it.

Comment: So I salute you and will walk away from it too. :) Thanks.
One more thing. Create an answer, I would like to give your the answer vote too.

Comment: Thanks but it seems so obvious. The error message said it. I just repeated what it said.

Comment: OK. If possible, I would be very grateful if you have a look at [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55190631/launch-image-isnt-shown-on-ios-app-xcode-10-1) too, please.