# xcode - webview content is showing in status bar

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am developing a webview app, which just loads our website.
I noticed that the content of the website is showing in the status bar if you scroll down the page. Is this default iOS browser behaviour or can I fix this?

[image: Website shows in status bar at the very top]

Comment: Is this in debug mode?

Comment: How do I know if it is?

Comment: You just build the app on a device right?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed, yes, I have an iPhone were I test the app

Comment: For next time, take an actual screenshot (not a photo of your screen). To do so on the simulator, press ⌘S; on an iPhone, press the lock button and volume up or down button simultaneously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add your top constraint (a controller with web site) to the safe area. I hope it will fix your problem
[image]

**EDITED**

Here is detailed screenshot how it's can be done:
(also, about constraints, check this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH10-SW1))

[image]

Comment: Where do I find this? Can you add more screenshots please, it would be really helpful.

Comment: Updated the answer, please, check it

Comment: In your screenshot there is View which has the children View and Safe Area. But I only have View which has the child "Safe Area". How can I add the other View?

Comment: There should be something like WebView (since you are displaying web content). Maybe web view is added in the code

Comment: If I click on safe area and try to add a constraint then everything is grayed out and I can't interact with the settings.

Comment: I restarted my project by following the following tutorial, now your answer works.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xQmZSKxOYvs

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 11 and upper OS create this issue during debug time. This will fix for the released version. I have faced this problem many times during work.

Don't know how but it happens.

So you can try to create a release version and check on your device.

Comment: How can I create the release version`?

Comment: have you publish any app on appstore?

Comment: No, thats my first one.

Comment: You need to know first how to export release version of ipa. Then install the ipa on your device and check.

Comment: This will help you to know: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499125/how-to-create-ipa-file-using-xcode/47940681

Comment: Ok, I have created the IPA, but how can I install it on my device?

Comment: 1. Open Xcode 2. Go Window > Devices and Simulators. 3 You can see your device is present 4. You can see installed Apps section and a plus icon in the bottom. Simply click the icon and select your iPA location and apply.

Comment: Ok, I managed to do it, I installed the IPA but the same error persist... so it is not the solution

Comment: Have you create the IPA using distribution certificate?

Comment: I created the IPA using iOS Developer certificate

Comment: I have created the IPA using distribution certificate and looks the issue is fixed. It's my personal experience.

Comment: My App has still transparent statusbar after release...

Answer (score 0):

The programmatically approach would be:

```
view.addSubview(webView)
let guide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.topAnchor).isActive = true
webView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
webView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```