# iOS App Failed to create provisioning profile

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm trying to publish my iOS app to the Apple Store ( it's my first time ) and I'm facing this error when I do the Automatically manage signs with XCode and choosing my team ( My Client Paid Account )

The Error `Failed to create provisioning profile`

After Some googling some fixes says I have to connect my real iOS device which I don't have, so do I need an iPhone to publish the app? and is there another way without an iPhone if this the issue?!!

The app developed in Ionic 4 ( web view/ cordova ) so I was debending on the similator and the browser on development and testing time.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need an actual iOS device to push to App Store but I am not sure. But here I think there might be two issues that might be causing this problem.

1. The application you have developed is not under the appstoreconnect account you have prepared to submit for. So goto project settings -> signing and capabilities and check if the Team you have selected is the team where you have prepared before the app submission.
2. Have you prepared you app in the appstoreconnect with the same bundle id before trying to archive the application? If not you have to go to appstoreconnect and register a iOS application giving the name, bundleId etc. before you archive the product.

After preparing the app you just select the generic iOS device from the devices panel and start archiving. It should probably archive without any issues.

Comment: In all tuts, they start by signing the app in XCode like this one https://youtu.be/YPLs3xrDcm0?t=301 then register the app id!! it's my first time so I'm kinda confused and I have asked my friend he says you just need to take the client iPhone serial and put it on the website.

Comment: I think you need to register the iPhone with UUID only if you wish to test it on the device. Otherwise it is not needed. Just go to Xcode preferences and try to login with your client Apple ID under the accounts section. Then go to Signing and capabilities and select the team. Before you do all this make sure you have already prepared you app in the App Store connect before submission.

Comment: Thanks so much, So is there any article or tutorial with those steps so I can follow exactly. I will be appreciated for you linked in here

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need an iPhone or an iPad to put an app in the AppStore. The path to the AppStore is a bit like gymnastics though. You should be able to follow all of these directions & be well on your way. Try this for [making an IPA file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499125/how-to-create-ipa-file-using-xcode#answer-47940681) and try this [to sign the app](https://ioscodesigning.com/generating-code-signing-files/)

Best of luck to you with your 1st app! I imagine you're very excited =)