# How to build ios .ipa file from xcode?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, flutter

**"Build xcode .ipa file then install iphone devices."**
Xcode version 13

Comment: Menu Product/Archive

Comment: you can try with this below several methods https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499125/how-to-create-ipa-file-using-xcode

Answer (score -1):

How to build ios .ipa file from xcode?:-
1.Go Product -> build
2.go to project navigation -> click product folder -> right click your project -> goto show in finder (that is spa file)

[image: step1]

[image: Step2]

"Build xcode .ipa file then install iphone devices." Xcode version 13:--

1. need to added device UDID in Development certificate
2. then upload file(use Appstore testflight,firebase distribution, some url there)
3. new install build that url